# Using DateListPlot and Plot

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to do an example of trig modelling.  Very simple, but hoping to use real data.  I can get weather data for where I live here, and it makes a pretty reasonable sinusoid

```
    DateListPlot[
 WeatherData["Edmonton", 
  "MeanTemperature", {{2005, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Month"}], 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: weather data]

I am looking for a VERY SIMPLE overlay of an actual sine graph,  period would be 1 year,  I'm guessing the midline would be about 5 degrees, amplitude is about 15 degrees, and phase shift is 0.

This is just as much a math question as a Mathematica question.  Like I said,  I don't need a trig regression, at least not for this example.  Just want to illustrate the process to my students,  approximate a, b, c and d in the general equation y = a + b sin c(x-d)  to show them a transformation of a function to reasonably match this data.  If I find a plot that is reasonable,  how do I overlay the two graphs?

Also,  I figured sunrise or sunset times would have been a better source of data, but didn't see anyway to access that from MMA,  though I could get it from Alpha.

Yes,  this is non-math major, non-Mathematica expert ,  lame question!  But help is appreciated.

Okay, with help from @b.gatessucks  I have made some progress, though I still value any feedback or help. 
So I get the weather data

```
data = WeatherData["Edmonton", 
   "MeanTemperature", {{2005, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Month"}];
```

changed the list to a numerical form,  where the first entry is the number of seconds since Jan. 1 , 1900

```
newdata1 = {AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ data
```

I wanted this graph to have more reasonable numbers to use as an example with high school students,  so I got the number of seconds up to Jan. 1, 2005  (where my data starts)

```
t1 = AbsoluteTime[{2005, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}]
```

and subtract this from every entry  so our time scale now has 0 at Jan. 1, 2005

```
newdata2 = {#[[1]] - t1, #[[2]]} & /@ newdata1
```

Now take that and divide by the number of seconds in year  since I'd like each 1 on the time axis to represent 1 year

```
year = 3.154 10^7
newdata3 = {#[[1]]/year, #[[2]]} & /@ newdata2
```

This gives this plot

[image: list plot]

Which now lets me write a sin function using "reasonable" numbers.  Note, I know this isn't a "fit"  , it was intended to be more of a visual exercise in transformations of sine function.

[image]

```
Show[ListPlot[newdata3, Joined -> True], 
 Plot[2 + 15 Sin[2 \[Pi] (x - 0.25)], {x, 0, 7}, PlotStyle -> Dashed],
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 7}, {-15, 20}}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to using sunrise data: Using `AstronomicalData` you have that at your fingertips.

```
AstronomicalData[
   "Sun", 
   {"NextRiseTime", {2012, 11, 4}, CityData[{"Edmonton", "USA"}, "Coordinates"]}, 
   TimeZone -> -6
]
```

> {2012, 11, 4, 6, 10, 41.507}

Your TimeZone may be one hour off depending on whether or not you are observing DST. It has been changed today I believe.

```
DateListPlot[
  Table[
    {#, AstronomicalData[
          "Sun", 
          {"NextRiseTime", #, CityData[{"Edmonton", "USA"}, "Coordinates"]}, 
          TimeZone -> -6
        ].{0, 0, 0, 1, 1/60, 1/3600}
    } &[DatePlus[{2005, 1, 1}, {d, "Day"}]], 
 {d, 0, 5*365, 10}],
 Joined -> True
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Sweet!  I figured that would be very, very symmetrical.  I read through AstronomicalData but just didn't see that.  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

You can make a fit to your data by converting dates to their numerical value. The following is a starting point :

```
data = WeatherData["Edmonton", "MeanTemperature", {{2005, 1, 1}, {2011, 12, 31}, "Month"}] ;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[{AbsoluteTime[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ data, 
   a + b Sin[c (t - d)], {a, b, c, d}, t, Method -> {NMinimize}];

DateListPlot[{data, {#[[1]], nlm[#[[1]] // AbsoluteTime]} & /@ data}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: plot]

You can find some suggestions about improving your fit [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2327/134).

Comment: The fitted sine looks rather bad due to the low number of sample points. I'd suggest you increase that.