# How can I fit a differential equation to experimental data?

Tags: differential-equations, fitting, modeling

I would like to add a fit to the following data. Here is the differential equation I am using. g=9.81   l=0.2    m=0.09

```
{((-g*Sin[y[x]])/(l)) - ((k)(y'[x]))/(m) == (y''[x]), y[0] == 1.22173, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3*Pi}
```

I need to find values for `k`.

[Here is the data](http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1518933165520.txt)

I've also added the data over [here](http://textuploader.com/dhytq).

You can copy-paste this data into mathematica, and it will work.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48690/134)

Comment: @kglr Please have a look.

Comment: How do I import your data in Mathematica?

Comment: @anderstood I believe you could just copy-paste it into mathematica? Does that work? I tried pasting the data here, but slashes appear at the end of each line.

Comment: @also, I get an error for the question being too much code.

Comment: I am trying to find a coefficient for k. g is 9.81, and m is 0.9

Comment: @anderstood Would that equation work for pendulums at large angles? Because the equation I have uses sintheta.

Comment: I have added the data, so are you able to copy paste it into mathematica?

Comment: Yes, just `l` is missing now. You should add them in the equation.

Comment: l=0.2, and g is 9.81. I need mathematica to find a value for k, and graph the fit.

Comment: @anderstood Hi, is it possible to come up with a good fit?

Comment: The data can be retrieved with `Most@ToExpression[
 "{" <> Import["http://m.uploadedit.com/bbtc/1518933165520.txt"] <> "}"]` -- there are minor syntax errors that are fixed with the braces and `Most`, at least currently.

Comment: Btw `k` for damping is a terrible notation... ($k$ usually denotes stiffness).

Comment: Ahh, its supposed to be b actually, in many books, but I usually use k for just about any constant.

Answer (score 2):

When we assume `g,l` and `m` are known fit is not good.

```
g = 9.81; l = 0.2 ; m = 0.09;

model[k_?NumberQ] := (model[k] = 
   Module[{y, x}, 
    NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == -g*Sin[y[x]]/l - k y'[x]/m, 
      y[0] == data[[1, 2]], y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3*Pi}]])

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k][x], k, x, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}];

Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 1]]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {k -> 0.405883}

[image]

We can do better than this when we assume we only know `g`.

```
 g = 9.81;

model[k_?NumberQ, l_?NumberQ, 
  m_?NumberQ] := (model[k, l, m] = 
   Module[{y, x}, 
    NDSolveValue[{y''[x] == -g*Sin[y[x]]/l - k y'[x]/m, 
      y[0] == data[[1, 2]], y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3*Pi}]])

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k, l, m][x], {k, l, m}, x, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}];

Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 1]]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {k -> 1.25031, l -> 0.298879, m -> 10.5371}

[image]

```
g = 9.81;

model[k_?NumberQ, 
  l_?NumberQ] := (model[k, l] = 
   Module[{y, x}, 
    NDSolveValue[{y''[x] + k y'[x] == -g*Sin[y[x]]/l, 
      y[0] == data[[1, 2]], y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 3*Pi}]])

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[k, l][x], {k, l}, x, 
   Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}];

Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, data[[-1, 1]]}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}, PlotRange -> All, 
 Frame -> True]
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> {k -> 0.119336, l -> 0.29895}

[image]

Comment: Hi, I entered your code, but I get the following errors: http://prntscr.com/igfays

Comment: Also, does it give a value for k? g, l, m are known constants, with g=9.81, l=0.2 and m=0.09

Comment: l and m are wrong values. So I fit them also. These are the values  `{k -> 1.25031, l -> 0.298879, m -> 10.5371}`

Comment: Actually m is very off. l is fine.. I don't know how you find m

Comment: Remove l and m from your code and use Clear[l,m]

Comment: I see, what code did you use to find k?

Comment: I think that is due to the fact that my experiment may not have been carried out well. It is to be noted that k/m is supposed to be a very small value, since there is supposed to be little to no friction.

Comment: maybe instead, remove the 'm' altogether? Then finally divide the k value by m?

Comment: m, g and l are supposed to be constants

Comment: I actually did my experiment using a length of 0.2meters, and a mass of 0.09 kilos. Would it be possible to remove the m, and the make the entire coefficient in front of y'[x] equal to k?

Comment: I did it manually, and let m=0.3 instead. https://prnt.sc/igmn2j  Would it be possible to make mathematica find the best value of k?

Comment: You mean l=0.3?

Comment: sorry, yes, l=0.3

Comment: I meant as in g and l are known, and the code is supposed to find a k-value.

Comment: @OmkarVaidya this is probably coming too late to help you.  But just glancing at the results vs your known values you probably have a unit conversion error.  I'm assuming m is mass in this case. So if it's off by a factor of 1000, that implies perhaps a gram vs kilogram unit mixup.

Answer (score 1):

The following finds the best fit (in some sense defined in the cost function). However based on the data and model you provided, the result is poor --- which is good for you, because having the solution directly from someone else is not very interesting anyway...

```
l = 0.2; g = 9.81; m = 0.9;
eq[k_] := -g/l*Sin[y[x]] - k*y'[x]/m == y''[x]; 
inter = Interpolation[data];
ic = {y[0] == inter[0], y'[0] == inter'[0]};
cost[k_?NumericQ] := Block[{sol},
  sol = NDSolveValue[{eq[k]}~Join~ic, y, {x, 0, 3}];
  NIntegrate[(sol[x] - inter[x])^2, {x, 0., 3}]]
FindMinimum[cost[k], {k, 4}]
```

Comment: is it possible to graph this over the data?