# Fitting data to a complicated function

Tags: fitting

So, where to begin. I have a certain dataset that I want to fit to a function. However, the function is rather complicated (matrix inversions, linearsolve) and does in general not have a closed form expression. I understand that this is quite a daunting task, but I'm going to attempt to go through with this, and see what is possible.

To begin with, I suppose I should set up a working example. The function is as follows

```
GammaEqCTFit[\[Omega]_?NumericQ, LL_, CC_, RR_, CCJ_, CC\[Kappa]_] := 
 Module[{ain = 1., K, 
   C\[Kappa]t, \[Kappa]1, \[Gamma]1, \[Gamma]2, \[Gamma]3, MC, 
   iC, \[Omega]1, \[Omega]2, \[Omega]3, J12, J23, J13, Dm, Av, r, Zc, 
   L1, L2, L3, CJ1, CJ2, CJ3, R1, R2, R3, C\[Kappa], C1, C2, C3},
  Zc = 50;
  L1 = LL; L2 = LL; L3 = LL;
  CJ1 = CCJ; CJ2 = CCJ; CJ3 = CCJ;
  R1 = RR; R2 = RR; R3 = RR;
  C\[Kappa] = CC\[Kappa];
  C1 = CC; C2 = CC; C3 = CC;
  K = 1 + (1/(Zc C\[Kappa] \[Omega]))^2; 
  C\[Kappa]t = C\[Kappa] (1 - 1/K);

  MC = ( {
     {C1 + C\[Kappa]t + CJ1 + CJ3, -CJ1, -CJ3},
     {-CJ1, C2 + CJ1 + CJ2, -CJ2},
     {-CJ3, -CJ2, C3 + CJ2 + CJ3}
    } );
  iC = Inverse[MC];

  \[Kappa]1 = 1/(K Zc ) iC[[1, 1]]; \[Gamma]1 = 
   1/R1  iC[[1, 1]]; \[Gamma]2 = 1/R2  iC[[2, 2]]; \[Gamma]3 = 
   1/R3  iC[[3, 3]];
  \[Omega]1 = Sqrt[1/L1 iC[[1, 1]]]; \[Omega]2 = Sqrt[
   1/L2 iC[[2, 2]]]; \[Omega]3 = Sqrt[1/L3 iC[[3, 3]]];
  J12 = 1/2 iC[[1, 2]]/Sqrt[iC[[1, 1]] iC[[2, 2]]]
     Sqrt[\[Omega]1 \[Omega]2];
  J23 = 1/2 iC[[2, 3]]/Sqrt[iC[[2, 2]] iC[[3, 3]]]
     Sqrt[\[Omega]2 \[Omega]3];
  J13 = 1/2 iC[[1, 3]]/Sqrt[iC[[1, 1]] iC[[3, 3]]]
     Sqrt[\[Omega]1 \[Omega]3];
  Dm = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"\[Omega]1", "-", "\[Omega]", "+", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"I", " ", "\[Gamma]1"}], "2"], "+", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"I", " ", "\[Kappa]1"}], "2"]}], "J12", "J13"},
{"J12", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]2", "-", "\[Omega]", "+", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"I", " ", "\[Gamma]2"}], "2"]}], "J23"},
{"J13", "J23", 
RowBox[{"\[Omega]3", "-", "\[Omega]", "+", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{"I", " ", "\[Gamma]3"}], "2"]}]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
         "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
          "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
          "ItemsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}, "Items" -> {}, 
          "ItemsIndexed" -> {}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\);
  Av = I Sqrt[{\[Kappa]1, 0, 0}] ain ;
  r = LinearSolve[Dm, Av];
  \[CapitalGamma] = 1 - Sqrt[{\[Kappa]1, 0, 0}].r/ain;
  Return[\[CapitalGamma]]
  ]
```

it looks very ugly when copy pasting, here is a picture instead (right click view for a bigger version). [image: here]

Alright, so, this beast is fully functional, but clearly not all that fast. I don't see an obvious way of speeding it up however, so, yeah. Next, we should perhaps generate a sample data set:

```
Freq = Range[6, 6.2, 0.005];
S11 = Table[
   GammaEqCTFit[2*Pi*Freq[[n]], 1.74, 300*10^-6, 20000, 30*10^-6, 
    1*10^-6], {n, 1, Length[Freq]}];
AbsS11 = Abs[S11];
DataTable = Table[{Freq[[n]], AbsS11[[n]]}, {n, 1, Length[Freq]}];
Export["CTTestData.dat", DataTable, "Table"]
ListPlot[Table[{Freq[[n]], AbsS11[[n]]}, {n, 1, Length[Freq]}], 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Freq (Ghz)", "Abs (\[CapitalGamma])"}]
```

which looks like this

[image]

I then load the data, and use the most obvious fitting function I could find

```
AbsS11Data = SetPrecision[Import["CTTestData.dat", "Table"], 25];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[AbsS11Data, 
  Abs[GammaEqCTFit[2*Pi*\[Omega], 1.74, 300*10^-6, 20000, 30*10^-6, 
    CC\[Kappa]]], {{CC\[Kappa], 5*10^-6}}, \[Omega], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

I've changed this part, incorporating the comments to this post. This example works, and gives the correct output. A problem is however that once I leave more than 1 parameter open, it again stops functioning. Say we take

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[AbsS11Data, 
  Abs[GammaEqCTFit[2*Pi*\[Omega], 1.74, 300*10^-6, 20000, CCJ, 
    CC\[Kappa]]], {{CCJ, 10*10^-6}, {CC\[Kappa], 5*10^-6}}, \[Omega], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

This no longer gives correct answers. It produces the message "The step size in the search has become less than the tolerance prescribed by the PrecisionGoal option, but the gradient is larger than the tolerance specified by the AccuracyGoal option. There is a possibility that the method has stalled at a point that is not a local minimum."

I've tried setting these parameters to higher values, like 25, but to no avail. So I'm not sure what to do from this point on.

I should add that I've looked at a few other posts on this topic, such as [Problem with NonlinearModelFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2309/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit/2327#2327) and some others. However, not only do the suggestions there not improve the result (using differential evolution and such), the problem there is often that no initial value is given. Now, I'm cheating here and putting it very close to the actual initial value, and even then it seems to fail, which is why I opened a new question.

Comment: Sorry to any readers before the edit, NonlinearModelFit can be used without a close form expression, that was my bad.

Comment: You should post here the `InputForm` of your expressions (no `Boxes`)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how that works. If I put InputForm around the expression, it returns null?

Comment: Thinking about the issue for a little while, I should probably take a different route. Maybe I can fit the J, omega, kappa and gamma values (no matrix inversion required) and work back from there.

Comment: Have you also checked that it is not a problem with numerical precision? Have you tried: 1) increasing the `WorkingPrecision`; 2) adding a constraint on `CCk` in `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Adding constraints doesn't help sadly; it'll converge to the upperbound I give, as long as its lower than the value it currently gives as output, the 0.002. As for the working precision.. I looked it up, and the default value is 16, correct? If I set it higher, I get a message like The precision of the data and model function (MachinePrecision) is \
less than the specified WorkingPrecision

Comment: You will have to set the input data to an arbitrarily higher precision as well; you could use `AbsS11Data = SetPrecision[Import["CTTestData.dat", "Table"], 25];`. You should also set the precision of the numerical parameters you fed to the model function, e.g. 1.74\`25; and of the initial guess: 0.5\`25*10^-6, and then you add `WorkingPrecision -> 25` as an option to `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Part of the problem is that in generating the data you use `2*Pi*freq[[n]]` and in fitting the model you drop the `2*Pi`.

Comment: @MarcoB I'll give that a try! And at Jim, you are very much correct, wow that was a big oversight. Great catch. That already improves the situation quite a bit.

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, that does indeed make it much better. Kind of tricky that one has to figure out a good value for himself.. Is there a way to get an idea of if you need to increase this precision, when you actually don't know what value you expect? And yeah, although this will help you in the case of 1 parameter, in the case of 2 it already starts to be troublesome again.

Comment: If you use starting values closer to the actual values it works for me.  In your example use 30*10^-6 instead of 10*10^-6 for CCJ.

Comment: You really should take the time to learn how to edit your question so it contains usable code. You need to take the pretty formatted matrices (`DM` for example) and change them back to `{{lists}}` before pasting to this site.

Comment: @george2079 I see what you mean. However, you can still copy this and paste it into Mathematica, right? So in that sense it is usable. And the picture below shows it in a legible format. But, of course, that is no alternative.

Comment: @JimBaldwin Yes, in that case it works, but that is because 30 is the actual value. My initial guess is not going to be that good I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is indeed about precision.  And just one main change seems to make it all work.  The line

```
Module[{ain = 1., K,
```

needs to be changed to

```
Module[{ain = 1, K,
```

Otherwise the function `GammaEqCTFit` does not return a number with enough precision.  Also, the parameters for `GammaEqCTFit` should be entered as rational numbers to keep the high precision.  Below I've added in a bit of random noise to be a more challenging test:

```
Freq = Range[6, 62/10, 5/1000];
AbsS11 = Abs[
   Table[GammaEqCTFit[2*Pi*Freq[[n]], 174/100, 300*10^-6, 20000, 30*10^-6, 1*10^-6],
    {n, 1, Length[Freq]}]];
(* Add in some random noise *)
SeedRandom[12345];
AbsS11 = AbsS11 + RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/30000], Length[Freq], 
  WorkingPrecision -> 25];
data = Transpose[{Freq, AbsS11}];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Abs[GammaEqCTFit[2*Pi*ω, 174/100, 300*10^-6, 20000, CCJ, CCκ]],
  {{CCJ, 32*10^-6}, {CCκ, 8^-7}}, ω, WorkingPrecision -> 25];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {CCJ -> 0.00002999980726002366869708664, CCκ -> 9.983725353089902821210579*10^-7} *)

Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Freq (Ghz)", "Abs (Γ)"}],
 Plot[nlm[x], {x, 6, 6.2}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image: Curve fit and data]