# Proper localization of variable names

Tags: variable-definitions

In functions like `NonlinearModelFit` I need to specify parameters with a symbol name. If I localize these parameters they get cluttered in the output (e.g.`"ParameterTable"`):

```
{a, b, c, d} = {2, 30, 4, 0};
data = a PDF[NormalDistribution[b, c], Range@100] + 
   RandomReal[{-.01, .01}, 100];

fitFunc[a_, b_, c_, d_, x_] := a PDF[NormalDistribution[b, c], x] + d

fit[data_] := Module[{a, b, c, d, aStart, nlmf},
  aStart = Max@data;
  nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
    fitFunc[a, b, c, d, x], {{a, aStart}, {b, 30}, {c, 4}, {d, 0}}, x];
  nlmf["ParameterTable"]
  ]

fit@data
```

How can I avoid outputs like `a$18554` in the the ParameterTable without using global symbol names for the parameters a, b, c, d inside `NonlinearModelFit`?

Comment: Do you care about the actual symbols used or just their appearance in the table? If the latter, you could use the package I posted [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/#18159) along with `Block` in place of `Module`. The parameters will all be renamed to things like `TransformedParameter$4` but will still display as the original symbols.

Comment: Could put the variable names in the input, as `fit[data_,vars_] := Module[...]` where you then use `vars` explicitly in the `Module`.

Comment: Have you considered using [Formal Symbols?](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264)

Comment: Some reasonable starting values to use (instead of the hard-coded ones) are `dStart = Min@data;
bStart = Position[data, Max@data] // Flatten // Mean;
cStart =
 Max[#] - Min[#] & @
   Flatten[Position[data, 
     Alternatives @@ 
      Select[data,  2 (# - dStart ) >= (Max@data - dStart) &]]] /2;
aStart = (Max@data - dStart)  cStart;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One brute force way is to convert parameters to strings:

```
fit[data_] := 
  Module[{a, b, c, d, aStart, nlmf}, aStart = Max@data;
      nlmf = NonlinearModelFit[data, fitFunc[a, b, c, d, x], 
            {{a, aStart}, {b, 30}, {c, 4}, {d, 0}}, x];
       nlmf["ParameterTable"] /. {a -> "a", b -> "b", c -> "c", d -> "d"}
  ]
```

Comment: This is not as elegant as I had hoped. But it is a working solution! Maybe I will ask for a more general solution in another question. Thx!