# Putting a matrix inside function

Tags: function-construction, fitting

I want to fit a function to some data and inside the function there's a list

here's my data

```
Ei = {{1, -0.00006636511699298353`}, {2, -0.00007582534298933297`}, \
{3, -0.00008658039298836684`}, {4, -0.00009882137899808185`}, {5, \
-0.0001127647090015671`}, {6, -0.00012865092799074773`}, {7, \
-0.00014674610198994742`}, {8, -0.00016733831999715676`}};
```

the list

```
racc = {6.0, 5.9, 5.8, 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.1};
```

and my function

```
U[r_] := ecc (1 - (racc[[r]] - Exp[-Acc (1 - rscc)])^2);
```

But mathematica shows my function as

```
ecc (1 - (-E^(-Acc (1 - rscc)) + {6., 5.9, 5.8, 5.7, 5.6, 5.5, 5.4, 
   5.3, 5.2, 5.1}[[r]])^2)
```

Though in someway it can understand it and give the result for function

```
U[3] /. {ehh -> 1, Ahh -> 1, rshh -> 1, ech -> 1, Achrsch -> 1, 
ecc -> 1, Acc -> 1, rscc -> 1};

-22.04
```

And it's able to fit it, although an giving an error

```
sol = FindFit[Ei, U[r], {ecc, Acc, rscc}, r]

Part::pspec: Part specification r is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>    
{ecc -> 3.45136*10^-6, Acc -> -21.5489, rscc -> 2.67028}
```

It can not Plot it

```
P2 = Plot[U[r] /. sol, {r, 1, 8}];
Part::pspec: Part specification 1.000143` is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
Part::pspec: Part specification 1.1430001428571428` is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
Part::pspec: Part specification 1.2858572857142856` is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>
General::stop: Further output of Part::pspec will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to put a matrix or list inside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try FromDigits[]

```
U[r_] := ecc (1 - (FromDigits[racc, r] - Exp[-Acc (1 - rscc)])^2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is  that your function `U` is defined only for integer `r`, whereas `FindFit` would want to sample the function at intermediate points as well. In this case, you can build the least squares by hand.
Additionally, your choice seems to be a poor fit; the vector `racc` decreases with its index, which makes your `U` increase so you won't get a good fit. Just for fun, I tried another fitting function with `racc` `Reverse`d.

```
bigU[r_] := ecc (1 - (racc[[r]] - Exp[-Acc (1 - rscc)])^2)
bigU2[r_] := ecc (1 - (Reverse[racc][[r]] - ex)^2)

sol = NMinimize[Total[(bigU[#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ Ei], {ecc, Acc, rscc}];
sol2 = NMinimize[Total[(bigU2[#[[1]]] - #[[2]])^2 & /@ Ei], {ecc, ex}];

ListPlot[{Ei, {#, bigU[#] /. sol[[2]]} & /@  Ei[[All, 1]], 
          {#, bigU2[#] /. sol2[[2]]} & /@ Ei[[All, 1]]}, Joined -> {False, True, True}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: is there a way to stop this error
    "Part::pspec: Part specification r is neither an integer nor a list of integers. >>"

I can not select any arrays or etc in find fit

Comment: You can make `U` a function of a generic real variable.

Comment: To clarify one point: `FindFit` (and `NonlinearModelFit`, which is based on it) do not sample at any other points than those given explicitly. That is what makes e.g. [this technique](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18159/312) possible.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks, I didn't know that and I had missed your answer.