# Non linear model fit

Tags: fitting

I need to fit this, but for some reason I cannot...

data = {{0.617,0.8}, {0.605,0.6}, {0.5997,0.4}, {0.5972,0.2}, {0.5985,0.1}};
soln = NonlinearModelFit[data, {y - 2478.82*w*log[k*c + 1]}, {y,w,k}, {c}, MaxIterations -> 1000]

I appreciate any help...Thanks!

Comment: Undefined function wlog? wlog= w Log? Space between k and c in kc?

Comment: You are attempting to estimate 4 parameters (`y`, `w`, `k`, and the error variance) with just 5 data points.  You've got to be kidding!  You need more data or a much, much simpler model or tell whoever has asked you to do this that it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 2):

After fixing the many typos you have (what is log? Mathematica uses Log), and adding a constraint on `k` else complex solution will result, here it is

```
data = {{0.617, 0.8}, {0.605, 0.6}, {0.5997, 0.4}, {0.5972, 0.2}, {0.5985, 0.1}};
soln = NonlinearModelFit[data, {y - 2478.82*w Log[k c + 1], k > 0},
      {y, w, k}, c, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There is still some warning about converge and the tolerance. You can play with options to try to eliminate these.

reference: [problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit-the-function-value-is-not-a-list-of-real-num](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31070/problem-with-nonlinearmodelfit-the-function-value-is-not-a-list-of-real-num)