# Does FindFit support complex numbers or doesn't it?

Tags: fitting, complex

Inspired by this previous question: [Findfit doesn't give the good fit; Changing the starting values will not change the results](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54838/484).

Consider the following complex-valued dataset.

```
f[t_] := b + a/(c + t)
data = Table[f[t] /. {a -> -1 - I, b -> 1 + I, c -> -5 + 2 I}, {t, 1, 10}] 
  + 0.1 RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, 10];
plot = ListPlot[Through@{Re, Im}@data]
```

[image]

Mathematica has no trouble fitting a linear model to it, and successfully finds complex values for the fit parameters.

```
g[t_] := u + v t;
lfit = FindFit[data, g[t], {u, v}, t]
(* {u -> 1.06445 + 1.59084 I, v -> -0.0604794 - 0.0647658 I} *)
Show[plot, Plot[Evaluate@Through@{Re, Im}@(g[t] /. lfit), {t, 1, 10}]]
```

[image]

It likewise has no trouble fitting the original nonlinear model to it if $c$ is held fixed.

```
fit = FindFit[data, f[t] /. c -> -5 + 2 I, {a, b}, t]
(* {a -> -1.00813 - 0.888072 I, b -> 0.960261 + 1.01034 I} *)
Show[plot, Plot[Evaluate@Through@{Re, Im}@(f[t] /. c -> -5 + 2 I /. fit), {t, 1, 10}]]
```

[image]

But make $c$ variable and suddenly it can't deal with complex numbers any more.

```
FindFit[data, f[t], {a, b, c}, t]
```

> FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {0.318749 -1.36562 I,0.294047 -1.31665 I,0.306199 -1.5257 I,0.339789 -1.54803 I,<<3>>,0.59458 -1.00036 I,0.343269 -0.994435 I,0.400584 -0.92625 I} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {10} at {a,b,c} = {1.,1.,1.}.

What gives?

Comment: Strongly related: "[Fitting complex data with NonlinearModelfit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18159/280)."

Comment: @Alexey: Ah, thanks for the link. I hadn't looked at that question carefully before; it does look like a duplicate. Although none of the answers there have realized why `FindFit` works in some cases but not in others, as Jens's answer here explains.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is a consequence of the special model that you're using. The parameters `a` and `b` appear only linearly, so as long as they are the only fit parameters it is clear that the best approach for `FindFit` would be to perform a simple `LeastSquares` calculation. This is a matrix method that works over the complex numbers, and that's why you get complex answers for the fit parameters `a` and `b` when you do

```
fit = FindFit[data, f[t] /. c -> -5 + 2 I, {a, b}, t]
```

**However**, when you add `c` as a parameter, it's no longer possible to go this route. Now, the parameters that are varied in `FindFit` **have** to be real. This is because for a nonlinear problem, `FindFit` uses `FindMinimum` to minimize a norm function (`Norm`), and `FindMinimum` allows only real (or integer) variables.

Comment: So this is the reason why explicitly using real-valued parameters and a custom norm-function works. +1

Answer (score 14):

For the reason why find fit fails when `c` is variable, please see the answer of Jens. One way to solve this is to use create the complex target function from real-valued parameters and set the `NormFunction` explicitely:

```
f1[t_] := (br + I bi) + (ar + I ai)/(cr + I ci + t)
fit = FindFit[data, f1[t], {ar, ai, br, bi, cr, ci}, t, 
   NormFunction -> (Norm[Re[#*Conjugate[#]]] & )];

Show[plot, Plot[Evaluate@Through@{Re, Im}@(f1[t] /. fit), {t, 1, 10}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The strangeness is that `FindFit` *can* determine the appropriate norm function in some cases but not in others.

Comment: I know this is beyond the scope of your answer but I was trying to use your method to find the data fit for the original linked question (using his data instead of the generated data in this question), and I got the error of "Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations." [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Velk0.png)
Do you know what I can do to fix this?

Comment: @seismatica, halirutan: `NormFunction -> (Re[#].Re[#] + Im[#].Im[#] &)` seems to work better.

Comment: Works like a charm (though I'd love to have someone explain to me why that would work). Thanks @RahulNarain!

Comment: @RahulNarain From researching on NormFunction it seems that you had chosen not do the square root for the typical 2-norm of FindFit--([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SQkVV.png)). May I know how that managed to overcome the "failed to converge error"? Also this leads me to another fundamental question about curve-fitting that may be obvious for someone stronger in math: why taking the root of the sum of squared differences when fitting curves to data?

Comment: @seismatica: In principle it is equivalent to minimize the total squared error or the square root of it, because the square root function is monotonic. However, from a numerical optimization perspective, it is better to minimize the total squared error directly, because it is smooth, quadratic, and generally well-behaved, while its square root is not as nice. That might be why the fitting is slow to converge when the square root is taken.

Comment: Yeah that's my understanding of your approach. My question then is why would anyone (including FindFit whose default NormFunction is Norm[#,2]&) use the square root of squared error to minimize residuals? Wouldn't a minimized sum of squared error means a minimized square root of that as well?

Comment: According to the Documentation, "`FindFit` by default finds a least-squares fit" and "`FindFit` effectively uses `FindMinimum` to minimize a norm of the residual function". But actually they return slightly different answers even if one supplies identical `NormFunction` and objective function for `FindMinimum`. But one thing is clear: specifying `Method -> "LevenbergMarquardt"` for `FindFit` does not change the output and does not produce an error as it does when one specifies `Norm[residual]` as objective function for `Findminimum`. So `FindFit` internally converts `Norm` into sum of squares.