# What is the difference between FindFit and NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting

I cannot get the difference between these two fitting functions in Mathematica. I even read in MMA that the result of these two are the same.

Comment: From my quick read the result of NonLinearModelFit is a 'FittedModel' object, which the result of FindFit is a 'list of replacement rules'.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that `FindFit` was first introduced in version 5 and updated in version 7.  Since then, `FindFit` has not been modified. `NonlinearModelFit` was introduced in 7 and appears to have remained unchanged since then.  The two use the same format for arguments; however, `FindFit` returns the best fit parameters whereas `NonlinearModelFit` returns a model.  The model has a wealth of statistical information included in it, and is referenced in current versions of the `FindFit` Documentation:

> [image]

The two functions seem to behave similarly both in their default behavior:

```
data = Table[{i, Exp[RandomReal[{i - 1, i}]]}, {i, 10}];
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Exp[a + b x], {a, b}, x][
   "BestFitParameters"];
ff = FindFit[data, Exp[a + b x], {a, b}, x];
nlm == ff
(* True *)
```

..and in their possible issues

```
model = a1 Exp[-(b1 (x - x1))^2] + a2 Exp[-(b2 (x - x2))^2];
data = Block[{a1 = 1, b1 = 5, x1 = -.5, a2 = 2, b2 = 10, x2 = .25, 
    x = Sort[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]]},
   Transpose[{x, model + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 100]}]];
fit = FindFit[data, model, {a1, b1, x1, a2, b2, x2}, x];
ffplot = Show[ ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[Evaluate[model /. fit], {x, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a1, b1, x1, a2, b2, x2}, x]
nlmplot = 
 Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[nlm[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red]]]
ffplot === nlmplot
(* True *)
```

The **bottom line**, `NonlinearModelFit` is the next generation of `FindFit` which provides more functionality and information about the fitted model, and there is likely no reason at this point in time to use `FindFit`.

Comment: I've found one difference between `NonLinearModelFit` and `FindFit`, and that is that `NonLinearModelFit` does not allow you to use the `NormFunction` to adjust how normalization as weighting is done.  By default `NonLinearModelFit` seeks to reduce the sum of the squares of the residuals, so it will be equivalent to `FindFit` with `NormFunction -> (Norm[Abs[#], 2] &)]`, as described [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/fitting-fractional-complex-data-with-nonlinearmodelfit/2787#2787).  While `NonLinearModelFit` is a bit "prettier", it does have some limitations in usage.

Comment: @iwantmyphd feel free to add another answer with your discovery and get some rep for it :-)

Comment: Good idea, will do. :-)

Answer (score 25):

I've found one difference between `NonLinearModelFit` and `FindFit`, and that is that `NonLinearModelFit` does not allow you to use the `NormFunction` to adjust how normalization as weighting is done. By default `NonLinearModelFit` seeks to reduce the sum of the squares of the residuals, so it will be equivalent to `FindFit` with `NormFunction -> (Norm[Abs[#], 2] &)]`, as described here. While `NonLinearModelFit` is a bit "prettier", it does have some limitations in usage.

Comment: Actually, `NonlinearModelFit` calls `FindFit` internally. The reason why it doesn't also support the `NormFunction` option is because some of the properties one can request for the `FittedModel` object only exist/have been implemented for the 2-norm. Thus, for the time being, `NonlinearModelFit` is restricted to the 2-norm only. The corollary is that if one is not interested in the properties anyway, there is no reason to use `NonlinearModelFit` rather than `FindFit` (the latter is faster, as it is kernel code, rather than being implemented at the top level).

Answer (score 3):

[`FindFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html) has the [`FitRegularization`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FitRegularization.html) option, which is missing from [`NonlinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html).