# Is there any reason to use FindFit over NonlinearModelFit?

Tags: fitting, nonlinear, function-comparison

Given that `FindFit` seems to just be able to return estimated coefficients and none of the other goodies (standard errors, confidence bands, residuals, etc.), under what circumstances might one want to ever use `FindFit`?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61340/what-is-the-difference-between-findfit-and-nonlinearmodelfit

Comment: I agree this question should be closed.  (My feeble response is that the original question that I duplicated didn't appear in the list of possible related questions - unless I missed it there, too.)