# FindFit gives poor regression

Tags: fitting, data

My code is

```
data = {{0, 0.00355}, {6, 0.00343}, {9, 0.00331}, {48, 0.00319}, {173, 0.00308}, {200, 0.00308}};
fun= FindFit[data, a*Exp[b*(x)] + c, {a, b, c}, x]
p[x_] := a*Exp[b*x] /. fun
```

This gives me {a -> -3.2091*10^-91, b -> 1., c -> 0.003312}

whereas when I use desmos it gives me:
[image: desmos]

where a=0.000437, b=-0.0598, and c=0.00310.

Desmos also gives the same answer as when I put it into wolfram alpha. I just want to know why my mathematica doesn't give me the same result and how I can make it give me the same as desmos. I have a lot of other data I would like to process in the same way and doing it all in desmos would be too painful.

Comment: Giving better starting values works:  `FindFit[data, a*Exp[b*(x)] + c, {a, {b, -1}, c}, x]`.

Comment: Try this `NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b x] + c, {a, b, c}, x, 
 Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"}, 
 MaxIterations -> 1000]
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just failed to converge (or rather, it converged to a bad fixed point). Use `Exp[-b x]` instead of `Exp[b x]`; this time it works as expected:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[-b x] + c, {a, b, c}, x]
(* {a -> 0.000436835, b -> 0.0584236, c -> 0.0031018} *)
```

Also, use `NonlinearModelFit` instead of `FindFit` (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/61340/34893) for more details).

Comment: I pasted your code in and it gave me:

General::munfl: -7.9988*10^-8/-6.277922286640201*10^7320 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: 3.9994*10^-8/3.138961143320101*10^7320 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::munfl: -6.88556*10^-8/-1.864483853397434*10^5969 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

General::stop: Further output of General::munfl will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: @Toadfuture huh, that's weird. Can you restart your kernel (run `Quit[]`) and try again? It works for me...

Comment: I quit the kernel and the errors still showed up but the fitted model output was what I wanted so I guess that's all I need. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Toadfuture A few messages about underflow may not be a serious problem: it just indicates that machine numbers were flushed to zero during intermediate calculations, which can happen when you use exponents. If the returned fit is good you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform `Method->"NMinize"`although solves the first case "...Exp[+b x]": `NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[ b x] + c, {a, b, c}, x, 
 Method -> "NMinimize"]`