# PredictionBands and the presence of {0,0} point

Tags: fitting, probability-or-statistics

We know from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4001/78), that the default fitting method cannot handle data with a {0,0} point, and that there are alternative methods.

But, with these alternative methods, the prediction bands property fails.

How to solve this?

```
newData = Table[{q, 2*q^2*RandomReal[{0.80, 1.2}]}, {q, 0, 2, 0.01}];
newModel = NonlinearModelFit[newData, a*q^b, {a, b}, q, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];
Show[ListPlot[newData], Plot[newModel["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95], {q, 0, 2}]]

(* FittedModel::nodm: Unable to compute an approximate design matrix because derivatives of the model could not be found. Some property values cannot be computed. *)
```

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be so much a problem with the fitting method.  Your model is actually linear, but values of zero are problematic for it.

Quoting from J. Johnston's Econometric Methods, edition 3, page 13:

> A linear specification means that Y, or some transformation of Y, can
>   be expressed as a linear function of X, or some transformation of X. 
>   In this sense,

```
Y = α + βX

Y = αX^β

and Y = exp{α + β 1/X}
```

> are all linear specifications.  The first is already linear in Y and
>   X.  The second, on taking logarithms of both sides of the equation,
>   may be written as

```
log Y = log α + β log X
```

> which is linear in log Y and log X.

To get around the problem of `Log[0.]` why not introduce small values?

E.g. comparing methods, first with the `{0., 0.}` point included:

```
newData = Table[{q, 2*q^2*RandomReal[{0.80, 1.2}]}, {q, 0, 2, 0.01}];
newModel = NonlinearModelFit[newData, a*q^b, {a, b}, q, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];
Normal[newModel]
```

> 1.9184111799203873 q^2.1104032823834475

```
newData[[1]]
```

> {0., 0.}

Setting small values:

```
newData[[1]] = {1.*^-100, 1.*^-100};
newModel2 = NonlinearModelFit[newData, a*q^b, {a, b}, q];
Normal[newModel2]
```

> 1.9184111852020502 q^2.110403278099661

The results are not much different.

Furthermore, upon checking, **`Method -> "PrincipalAxis"`** doesn't actually help for this model:

With the small values included the `"PrincipalAxis"` method gives the same result as before (when the zeros were used), indicating that it is less precise than the default method.

```
newModel = NonlinearModelFit[newData, a*q^b, {a, b}, q, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];
Normal[newModel]
```

> 1.9184111799203873 q^2.1104032823834475

Plotting the bands with the default method (and small values replacing zeros):

```
Show[ListPlot[newData], Plot[newModel2["SinglePredictionBands",
   ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95], {q, 0, 2}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If the data *and the error* follows a power law, it makes sense to do the fit in log log space.
To do that I'm dropping zero/negative data:

```
newData = 
     Select[ Table[{q, 2*q^2*RandomReal[{0.80, 1.2}]}, {q, 0, 2, 0.01}] , 
        #[[1]] > 0 && #[[2]] > 0 &] ;
newModel = 
     NonlinearModelFit[Log[newData], a*q + b, {a, b}, q, Method -> "PrincipalAxis"];
Show[{
        ListPlot[newData],
        Plot[ Exp[newModel[Log[q]]] , {q, .1, 2}],
        Plot[ Exp[ 
          newModel["SinglePredictionBands", ConfidenceLevel -> 0.95] ]  /. 
             q -> Log[lq] , {lq, .1, 2}]}]
```

[image]

for comparison, your model with the exact zero dropped from the data looks like this:

[image]