# In finding a logarithmic fit for some data (of the form a*Log[b*x]), WolframAlpha succeeds where Mathematica 7.0 fails, why?

Tags: fitting, wolfram-alpha-queries

I would like to fit a function of the form: $a \log(b x)$ to a set of data:

```
data = {{10, 10/153}, {100, 100/1833}, {200, 200/3814}, {300, 300/5847}, {500, 500/10006},
        {625, 625/12649}}
```

The input string to WolframAlpha:
[`"log fit {{10, N[10/153,16]},{100,N[100/1833,16]},{200,N[200/3814,16]},{300,N[300/5847,16]},{500,N[500/10006,16]},{625,N[625/12649,16]}}"`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+fit+%7B%7B10%2C+N%5B10%2F153%2C16%5D%7D%2C%7B100%2CN%5B100%2F1833%2C16%5D%7D%2C%7B200%2CN%5B200%2F3814%2C16%5D%7D%2C%7B300%2CN%5B300%2F5847%2C16%5D%7D%2C%7B500%2CN%5B500%2F10006%2C16%5D%7D%2C%7B625%2CN%5B625%2F12649%2C16%5D%7D%7D) produces a nice logarithmic fit of this data.  However, using `FindFit` with my copy of *Mathematica* 7.0 produces nonsensical values for $(a,b)$ and/or complex functions.  How did WolframAlpha produce this fit, and how might I find this fit using my copy of *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm using 8.0.4 and I get reasonable results (notice the constraint `c>0`) :

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, {a + b Log[c x], c > 0}, {a, b, c}, x] ;

nlm // Normal
(* 0.0740508 - 0.00391526 Log[1.0714 x] *)

FindFit[data, {a + b Log[c x], c > 0}, {a, b, c}, x]
(* {a -> 0.0740508, b -> -0.00391526, c -> 1.0714} *)

Show[Plot[nlm[x], {x, 10, 625}, PlotRange -> All], 
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]]]
```

[image: plot]

The fit without an additive constant looks much worse :

```
nlm2 = NonlinearModelFit[data, {b Log[c x], c > 0}, {b, c}, x] ;

nlm2 // Normal
(* 0.0094653 Log[1.07146 x] *)

FindFit[data, {b Log[c x], c > 0}, {b, c}, x]
(* {b -> 0.0094653, c -> 1.07146} *)

Show[Plot[nlm2[x], {x, 10, 625}, PlotRange -> All], 
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]]]]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: Right, I didn't properly constraint c>0.  I suppose WolframAlpha is better at curve fitting somehow.  Odd given that it should use the same functions as Mathematica...

Comment: fyi, simplifying the expression to just a*Log[b*x] produces basically the same residuals.

Comment: Identical results in 7.0.1, FWIW. @Ski: see my related answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9878/312)--you do not need any constraints using this approach. I've been working on a package to do this transformation automatically but have not had time to finish it so far.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth understanding that WolframAlpha is *not* a direct interface to Mathematica.  Even if you type an exact Mathematica command, WolframAlpha will parse it and interpret it - perhaps in a different way.  For example, the following two WolframAlpha inputs yield the exact same results:

[image]

Furthermore, *none* of those results matches the output of `Solve[x^5-x-1==0,x]` - so it's simply not the case that the `Solve` command is being called inside of WolframAlpha as you might expect.

Now, your input doesn't even correspond directly to a Mathematica command, so I'm really not sure what you're expecting.  If you have basic enough input (which I think we do in this case) and you want to see what commands WolframAlpha sent to Mathemtatica to generate various outputs, you might try the following in Version 8:

```
WolframAlpha[
  "log fit {{10, N[10/153,16]},{100,N[100/1833,16]},{200,N[200/3814,16]},{300,N[300/5847,16]},{500,N[500/10006,16]},{625,N[625/12649,16]}}",
  "MathematicaForms"]
```

In the sea of output you'll notice the `NonlinearModelFit` command.