# FindFit::nrlnum What am I doing wrong?

Tags: fitting, warning-messages, complex

I have a model called qobs:

```
qobs=0.039 ns (T (8.314 + (8.314 - 8.314 m) Hypergeometric2F1[1., 1/m, 
    1. + 1/m, (ns/ns∞)^m] + 
  8.314 Log[-1. (A E^((0.120279 ΔE)/T))^(-1./
      m) (-1. + 1/(1. - 1. (ns/ns∞)^m))^(-1./
      m) (1/(-1. + 1. (ns/ns∞)^m))^1. (ns/
      ns∞)^(1. m) Psat[T]]) + 1. λp[T])
```

I have a set of data with two independent variables (ns and T):

```
Data = {{0, 85, 0}, {0.131592244, 85, 69.07308925}, {0.230286428, 85, 
115.4518887}, {0.255592629, 85, 126.8281889}, {0.382123633, 85, 
181.8483799}, {0.426409484, 85, 200.2798617}, {0.516246497, 85, 
237.7531003}, {0.60102227, 85, 271.3000332}, {0.642777502, 85, 
288.766803}, {0.749063545, 85, 329.4612163}, {0.760451336, 85, 
332.9712438}, {0.762981956, 85, 334.6336615}, {0, 100, 
0}, {0.074653293, 100, 39.4734225}, {0.111347284, 100, 
57.64231052}, {0.127796314, 100, 65.7007577}, {0.212572087, 100, 
104.7308741}, {0.269511039, 100, 130.1461666}, {0.29481724, 100, 
141.0225864}, {0.408695144, 100, 189.1969421}, {0.523838358, 100, 
236.109073}, {0.536491458, 100, 241.0802459}, {0.551675179, 100, 
247.1796371}, {0.58710386, 100, 261.1558457}, {0.632655021, 100, 
278.7613986}}
```

Other known values within the model are:

```
λp[85] = 6540
λp[100] = 6540
Psat[85] = 78896.6
Psat[100] = 323767
R = 8.314
```

I have tried using FindFit:

```
 FindFit[Data, qobs, {ns∞, m, A, ΔE}, { ns, T}]
```

And I get the error code:

```
FindFit::nrlnum: "The function value {0.,-69.0731+0.0051321\ (85.\ (8.314 +8.314\ Log   
[<<1>>])+1.\ λp[85.]),<<21>>,-261.156+0.0228971\ (100.\ (8.314 +8.314\ Log
[<<1>>])+1.\ λp[100.]),-278.761+0.0246735\ (100.\ (8.314 +8.314\ Log[<<1>>])+1.
\ λp[100.])} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {25} at {ns
∞,m,A,ΔE} = {1.,1.,1.,1.}. "
```

I found, what I thought was a similar problem here [how to avoid inducing complex numbers in FindFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/using-findfit-to-fit-a-bt-how-to-avoid-introducing-complex-numbers)

In particular the answer suggested by Oleksandr R. which involves splitting the model into explicitly real and imaginary parts and changing the data to force the imaginary part of the model to go to zero.  Hence I changed my model to:

```
ComplexModel = Inner[#1[qobs] KroneckerDelta[i, #2] &, transformation, 
Range@Length[transformation]]
```

where

```
transformation = {Re, Im}
```

and I reformatted my data to:

```
ComplexData = {{1, 0, 85, 0}, {1, 0.131592244, 85, 69.07308925}, {1, 
0.230286428, 85, 115.4518887}, {1, 0.255592629, 85, 
126.8281889}, {1, 0.382123633, 85, 181.8483799}, {1, 0.426409484, 
85, 200.2798617}, {1, 0.516246497, 85, 237.7531003}, {1, 
0.60102227, 85, 271.3000332}, {1, 0.642777502, 85, 288.766803}, {1,
0.749063545, 85, 329.4612163}, {1, 0.760451336, 85, 
332.9712438}, {1, 0.762981956, 85, 334.6336615}, {1, 0, 100, 
0}, {1, 0.074653293, 100, 39.4734225}, {1, 0.111347284, 100, 
57.64231052}, {1, 0.127796314, 100, 65.7007577}, {1, 0.212572087, 
100, 104.7308741}, {1, 0.269511039, 100, 130.1461666}, {1, 
0.29481724, 100, 141.0225864}, {1, 0.408695144, 100, 
189.1969421}, {1, 0.523838358, 100, 236.109073}, {1, 0.536491458, 
100, 241.0802459}, {1, 0.551675179, 100, 247.1796371}, {1, 
0.58710386, 100, 
261.1558457}, {1, 0.632655021, 100, 278.7613986} {2, 0, 85, 0}, {2,
0.131592244, 85, 0}, {2, 0.230286428, 85, 0}, {2, 0.255592629, 85,
0}, {2, 0.382123633, 85, 0}, {2, 0.426409484, 85, 0}, {2, 
0.516246497, 85, 0}, {2, 0.60102227, 85, 0}, {2, 0.642777502, 85, 
0}, {2, 0.749063545, 85, 0}, {2, 0.760451336, 85, 0}, {2, 
0.762981956, 85, 0}, {2, 0, 100, 0}, {2, 0.074653293, 100, 0}, {2, 
0.111347284, 100, 0}, {2, 0.127796314, 100, 0}, {2, 0.212572087, 
100, 0}, {2, 0.269511039, 100, 0}, {2, 0.29481724, 100, 0}, {2, 
0.408695144, 100, 0}, {2, 0.523838358, 100, 0}, {2, 0.536491458, 
100, 0}, {2, 0.551675179, 100, 0}, {2, 0.58710386, 100, 0}, {2, 
0.632655021, 100, 0}}
```

I tried to use FindFit again:

```
FindFit[ComplexData, ComplexModel, {ns∞, m, 
A, ΔE}, {i, ns, T}]
```

however I am still getting an error code:

```
FindFit::nrlnum: The function value {0.,-69.0731+0.0051321 Re[85. (8.314 +Times
[<<2>>])+1. λp[85.]],<<45>>,0. +0.0228971 (831.4 Im[Log[Times[<<2>>]]]+1. Im
[λp[100.]]),0. +0.0246735 (831.4 Im[Log[Times[<<2>>]]]+1. Im[λp
[100.]])} is not a list of real numbers with dimensions {49} at {ns∞,m,A,
ΔE} = {1.,1.,1.,1.}. >>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just for reference, I know the manual transformation can be a bit tedious, so I [wrote a package](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43232/nonlinearmodelfit-does-not-find-a-good-fit/43237#43237) to do it automatically. `ComplexFit[Data, qobs, {ns∞, m, A, ΔE}, {ns, T}, "CoordinateSystem" -> "Real"]` will do what you want. Of course, @m_goldberg's answer is absolutely correct.

Comment: Wow, @OleksandrR.  I can see where that could be a very useful package.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My reading of the error message you are getting is that if you try

```
λp[85.] = 6540
λp[100.] = 6540
Psat[85.] = 78896.6
Psat[100.] = 323767
```

your original formulation might work. `λp[100]` is not the same as `λp[100.]`. Similarly for `λp[85]` and `Psat`, too.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg, that has helped!  Now I've gone from a _FindFit::nrlnum:_ error code to a _FindFit::sszero:_ error code.  I'm going to try giving it some initial values to start from and we'll see what happens.

Comment: Bingo!  Thanks again to m_goldberg.  Between your suggestion of formatting as 'λp[85.] = 6540' and Oleksandr R's earlier example of how to break a FindFit model into Real and Imaginary parts, all it took were some good initial guesses for the parameter values and it all seems to be working.  Fantastic!