# NonlinearModelFit gives imaginary numbers

Tags: fitting

I am having trouble using `NonlinearModelFit` to fit to data generated by the equation I am trying to fit to.

```
test = Table[{x, ((Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[x + 3])^2)^(2/3) - 
                  Sqrt[3 ((Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[x + 3])^2)^(1/3)] - 
                 ((Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[3])^2)^(2/3) - 
                  Sqrt[3 ((Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[3])^2)^(1/3)] + 5},
             {x, -3, 5, .1}
            ]
```

Here is the data I generated with the equation.

```
 Blah = ListPlot[test]
```

[image: Plot of data]

This is what it looks like

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
  test, ((Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[F + y])^2)^(2/3) - 
   Sqrt[y ((Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[F + y])^2)^(1/
     3)] - ((Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[y])^2)^(2/3) - 
   Sqrt[y ((Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[y])^2)^(1/3)], {y}, F]
```

My attempt to fit. The error says there are imaginary numbers yet there are none.

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` tries negative `y`. Try adding `y>0` as a constraint. You might also use `Abs[y]` in the expression.

Comment: ( actually you need `y>=3` )

Comment: @george2079: `F >= 3`, surely?

Comment: you need `F+y>=0` where `F` has a min value of `-3` from the data.  ( his choice of variables is a bit confusing, `y` is the fit parameter `F` is the independent data value)

Comment: Not really sure how to implement these constraints.

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of [(1898)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1898/using-findfit-to-fit-a-bt-how-to-avoid-introducing-complex-numbers), and the same solution is probably applicable. [(2784)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2784/fitting-fractional-complex-data-with-nonlinearmodelfit) may also help you.

Answer (score 4):

Here it is with the constraint.  I changed the symbols to `a,x` just for readability (There was nothing wrong with the `y,F` except that single Caps are good to avoid )

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   test,
    {((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[x + a])^2)^(2/3) - 
          Sqrt[a ((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[x + a])^2)^(1/3)] - ((Sqrt[a] + 
          Sqrt[a])^2)^(2/3) - Sqrt[a ((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[a])^2)^(1/3)]
            +5 , (* constraint *) a >= 3}, {a}, x];

 nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

> ```
> {a -> 3.}
> ```

You were also missing the `+5`..btw.

Answer (score 2):

The following trick sometimes work:

```
f[a_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{s = ((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[x + a])^2)^(2/3) - 
               Sqrt[a ((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[x + a])^2)^(1/3)] - ((Sqrt[a] + 
               Sqrt[a])^2)^(2/3) - Sqrt[a ((Sqrt[a] + Sqrt[a])^2)^(1/3)] + 5},
        10^3 Im@s + Re@s]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[test, {f[a, x]}, {a}, x, 
                       Method -> {"NMinimize", Method -> "SimulatedAnnealing"}]

nlm["BestFitParameters"] 
(* {a -> 3.} *)
```